# /var/run/docker.sock unaccessible in container running on centos 7

Tags: sockets, docker, selinux, centos7

I'm launching a container which runs a bash script that does a docker build internally using docker 1.3.2 on Centos 7.0.1406 . The files/commands are at https://gist.github.com/wrabbit-revisited/1d70d0f1805be1848c08 .

The docker build needs access to the docker socket so i use a common trick, as per http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/07/12/10-docker-tips-and-tricks-that-will-make-you-sing-a-whale-song-of-joy/ :

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Prior to the build i run a check in the script:

```
if [ -e "/var/run/docker.sock" ];
then
  echo "docker.sock found"
else
  echo "docker.sock not found"
fi
```

and the "echo" shows that docker.sock is not found. It is found if the check is done outside the container using sudo.

I tried adding "--permissive=true" to the "docker run" command line, but no apparent change.

There is some reference to a similar problem here: https://github.com/dpw/selinux-dockersock . It targets Fedora/RHEL, but doesn't resolve this issue, either. If i use "setenforce Permissive" and sestatus to ensure selinux is in permissive mode the issue remains unresolved.

I've also tried adding "--security-opt=label:type:docker_t" to the docker command line, as per https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/40 . No apparent effect.

The selinux policy for Docker is described here: http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/docker_selinux/ .

Lots of information, but i'm not sure if selinux is contributing to the problem. If i edit /etc/selinux/config to disable selinux then reboot and run sestatus it says selinux is disabled, but the issue remains.

Looking about, it may be related to this: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/983 . Using this trick to run docker inside a container is quite common but perhaps there is a better way to do this or a good workaround. I considered dind, but that's work and this is a widely-used, simple (on the surface), approach to running a docker build inside a container. There is probably a simple solution.

Any help would be appreciated!
thanks

Comment: Just tried it on ubuntu 14.04 desktop with docker 1.2.0 . The build.sh running in the container was able to find /var/run/docker.sock so this issue  seems to be Centos 7-specific. BTW it's necessary to make build.sh executable before building the docker image.

Comment: We were able to get DockerUI working on RHEL/CentOS by using the `--privileged` flag. It's a bit of a sledgehammer and I'd be glad to learn about a better approach.

Comment: Yep.. currently Docker is a bit of a moving target, particularly wrt security. Not a blocker for me currently - i moved to Ubuntu 14.04 to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I think your problem might be due to a misunderstanding of the `-v` option to `docker run`.  You say you did

```
-v /var/run/docker:/var/run/docker
```

This creates a bind mount in the container for the file or directory `/var/run/docker`.  But in your case, there is no such file or directory. You want the file `/var/run/docker.sock`.  So you need to do

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

to bind mount that file into the container.

As `/var/run/docker` didn't exist, you might wonder why docker didn't tell you about the error.  But the `-v` option has the surprising behaviour that if the path does not exist on the host, docker will create it as a directory.  So you end up with a useless empty `/var/run/docker` directory on the host and container.

In principle, you could also do `-v /var/run:/var/run` to bind mount the containing directory.  But it's probably a bad idea to give a container access to the host's `/var/run` directory tree.

And as you are on CentOS, you will also need to use https://github.com/dpw/selinux-dockersock for access to /var/run/docker.sock to work with SELinux in enforcing mode.

Comment: Thanks for your input, David. The question has a typo - the gist has the actual command line and it does use docker.sock.

Comment: Thanks @David selinux-dockersock was essential!

Answer (score 4):

Confirmed installing https://github.com/dpw/selinux-dockersock is enough and good in the long run.

A quick alternative fix is to pass `--privileged` argument, when starting a container.

Comment: Note for those who use CentOS 7. selinux-dockersock doesn't work with CentOS 7. In the issues you will find an updated module. Took me some time to realize this.